# How to maintain a large number of videos on an asp website

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am developing a website in ASP.NET 3.5 which involves a large number of videos. I am using XML to save the links of the files. Currently, I am facing space issues due to large number of videos. Please suggest how to overcome the problem.

Comment: Uhm...get a bigger hard drive? (Not trying to be unhelpful, but that's honestly the best thing I can think of with the detail provided in your question.)

Answer (score 1):

If the number of videos is very large, you will need to move to a more effective storage mechanism than a simple XML file.  I'd suggest a database engine (Firebird would likely be suitable for your needs).

Comment: thanks fo ur concern but tell me is it true that storing videos and images in a database by converting them into binary reduces the size?

Comment: lol - I was assuming you were having memory issues because of issues with a large number of files (large index xml).  If your issue is really just the size of the videos themselves, no a DB won't help.  In that case, the other (obvious) answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Larger hard drive or place them on something like You Tube and embed the videos.  Not much choice unless you can use a different comprssion codec and reduce the quality which would in turn reduce the size.